# Unresolved Reference layoutInflater Android View Binding

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-viewbinding, groupie

I'm trying to convert one of my former "kotlin-android-extensions" activities to View Binding.  Every example I've seen of this seems to contain some variant of the line:

```
binding = MyActivityBiding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

Yet when I attempt to use layoutInflater I get the error:

```
Unresolved reference: layoutInflater
```

I understand it appears to be a variable from Layoutinflater... but no one ever seems to need to define it in any of the examples I've found. And when I attempt to define "layoutInflater" myself using LayoutInflater... I can never get the context from anywhere.

Anyway... here is my code:

```
open class ExpandableCommentIndie   constructor(
        private val comment : Comment,
        private val depth : Int) : Item<GroupieViewHolder>(), ExpandableItem {

    private lateinit var expandableGroup: ExpandableGroup
    private lateinit var binding: ItemEcBinding




    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        addingDepthViews(viewHolder)
        binding = ItemEcBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        binding.tvUser.setText(comment.speaker.toString())
    }
```

Comment: Does GroupieViewHolder extend RecyclerView.ViewHolder?

Comment: I'm not sure. You think that's what's holding up the layoutInflater?

Comment: If it is then it's easy to get a LayoutInflater. Please check your code and post the beginning of the GroupieViewHolder code

Comment: It's part of a plugin and it appears to extend RecyclerView: https://github.com/lisawray/groupie/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/xwray/groupie/GroupieViewHolder.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to get a `LayoutInflater` is a `Context` which is somehow related to a UI component. So `Activity` (which is a kind of `Context`), `Fragment.context` and `View.context` will do.

Since `GroupieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, it has a property `itemView: View`. So you can get the `LayoutInflater` as follows:

```
val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewHolder.itemView.context)
```

The whole function:

```
override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
    addingDepthViews(viewHolder)
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewHolder.itemView.context)
    binding = ItemEcBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    binding.tvUser.setText(comment.speaker.toString())
}
```